# Show modal form before ajax cal and get data from it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function something like this:

```
 function foo(e, e1, curc)
 {
    var sender = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'script.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "id="+e+"&mod="+e1+"&curc="+curc, 
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#mform').show();             
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#fountainG').hide();
        }, 
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("itog").innerHTML = data.d+data.a;
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            document.getElementById("itog").innerHTML = '123';
        }    
    });
}
```

I need to show some modal form to user, and get the data from it in ajax script. I tried to add show function to ajax beforeSend - but I do not understand how to wait for user form submit, and get data from modal form. Ajax function call in html: `href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:foo(3800064420557,1,138)`

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1vczLnco/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to re-arrange your logic.  Instead of trying to show the modal "within" the ajax request, hold off on sending the ajax request until you have gotten the necessary data from the modal.  Here is a rough outline, presuming that your modal element `$('#mform')` has a form in it with an id of myform which is the form you want to get data out of.

```
function foo(e, e1, curc)
 {
    var sender = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);

    var modal = $('#mform');
    var form = $('#myform', modal);
    form.on( 'submit', function(){
        $('mform').hide();

        // make your ajax call here the same way, and inside the
        // onsuccess for this ajax call you will then have access to both
        // the results of your ajax call and the results of the form
        // data from your modal.
        $.ajax({ ... });
    });
}
```

Comment: Please, help me once more - how to get data from form in ajax? e.g. from input type="text" name="mi" id="mi"

Comment: You have a couple options.  You can serialize the from to get all of its input out using either serialize (which will return a string that can be sent out in an ajax request) or serializeArray (which will return an object you can access easily in code): `console.log( form.serialize() )`.  If you lookup those two methods in the jQuery documentation you will get more details on how they work.  The exact answer though, depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Also, if you need just the value of a particular input, you can add a class or id to it, find it with jQuery, and then get its value.  Without a class or id you can also use an attribute selector and fine the input using its name: `console.log( $("input[name='mi']", form).val() )`

Answer (score 1):

To get form data, you can try with below code

```
function foo(e, e1, curc)
 {
    var sender = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);
   form_values = {}
   $('mform').show();
   $('#myForm').submit(function() {
   var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');
       $inputs.each(function() {
       form_values[this.name] = $(this).val();
   }); 
   console.log("form data:", form_values)
   // with form_values continue with your coding   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'script.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "id="+e+"&mod="+e1+"&curc="+curc, 
        success: function(data) {
            $('mform').show();
            document.getElementById("itog").innerHTML = data.d+data.a;
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            document.getElementById("itog").innerHTML = '123';
        }    
    });
  });
}
```

Hope it will help you :)